# BIRT crosstab hiding of column and rows does not reflect when export to excel/pdf

Tags: report, birt

I have monthyear for column dimension and modelnames for row dimension.  I need to display all monthyears and modelnames regardless if a modelname was used for that monthyear.  In order to accomplish this, I did outerjoin in my dataset.  I was able to accomplish this however, there is an extra blank column and blank row in the generated report.  I was able to remove this also by using the following code:

```
if(cellInst.getDataValue("MONTHYEAR") == ""){
    cellInst.getStyle().setDisplay("none");
}
if(cellInst.getDataValue("MODELDESCRIPTION") == ""){
    cellInst.getStyle().setDisplay("none");
}
```

Thus, the extra blank column and blank row was removed.  However, when I tried to export to excel, the blank column and blank row still shows.  When I export to pdf, only the blank column shows.

I even tried this in onRender(), however nothing happens

```
if(cellInst.getDataValue("MONTHYEAR") == ""){
    reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(cellInst.getCellID()).setStringProperty("width","0px"); 
}
if(cellInst.getDataValue("MODELDESCRIPTION") == ""){
    reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(cellInst.getCellID()).setStringProperty("height","0px"); 
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: you have the visibility option for all reports did u check that ?

Comment: visibility is for element. i tried that as well, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this

```
if(reportContext.getOutputFormat()=="xls"){
this.action = null;
}
if(reportContext.getOutputFormat()=="pdf")
this.action = null;
}
```